# `require': no such file to load -- lib/book (LoadError) on Heroku, Sinatra

Tags: heroku, sinatra

I have created a simple app and this is my folder structure

- lib/book.rb
- lib/user.rb
- server.rb <- main sinatra file

And this is my config.ru

```
require './server'
run Sinatra::Application
```

When I deploy to heroku I got this error `require': no such file to load -- lib/book (LoadError). However, on my local machine it works fine.

I'm not sure what to include in config.ru I tried require './lib/book' as well, but it didn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add the /lib directory to your `$LOAD_PATH` by adding something like this to your `server.rb`:

```
configure do
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib")
  Dir.glob("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib/*.rb") { |lib| 
    require File.basename(lib, '.*') 
  }
end
```

This will add the /lib directory to your `$LOAD_PATH` and require all *.rb files in it.